# Смена style при определенном разрешении экрана

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно прописать условие в *jquery*:

Если `aside.left_panel` имеет `style="display: none;"` при разрешении экрана больше `600px`, то сменить в `aside.left_panel` на `style="display: block"`.

Как можно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: посмотри медия запросы css, просто css

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужно обрабатывать именно ширину экрана, а не область отображения браузера? Если только браузер а, то это можно сделать средствами css, что более удачный вариант нежели js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного исправлю предыдущего комментатора:

```
function screen_check(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 600) { 
       $('.left_panel').style('display', 'block');
    } else {
       $('.left_panel').style('display', 'none');
    };
}

screen_check();
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    screen_check();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерно так:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
       if ($(this).width() > 600) { 
           $('.left_panel').style("display": "block");
       } else {
           $('.left_panel').style("display": "none");
       } 

    });
```

Comment: Немного исправлю:

function screen_check(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 600) { 
       $('.left_panel').style('display', 'block');
    } else {
       $('.left_panel').style('display', 'none');
    };
}

screen_check();
$(window).on('resize', function(){});

Answer (score 1):

```
.left_panel {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (min-width:600px) {
  .left_panel {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

PS: Сколько ж можно пихать скрипты куда ни попадя?

Comment: ps:не всегда верно

Comment: @SergeoAyshev, не всегда, но весьма часто. Чем этот вариант не подходит? Нигде не вижу чтобы что-то написано на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

и еще пару исправлений и нормально:

```
function screen_check(){
if ($(window).width() >= 600) { 
   $('.left_panel').css('display', 'block');
} else {
   $('.left_panel').css('display', 'none');
};}
```